# Find logic behind best approach

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve an online judge problem. Problem description:

Here is the original problem: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1090

Here the full list of inputs:
http://maratona.ime.usp.br/hist/2008/primeira-fase/testset2008/principal/G.in
(warning: huge size ~10mb file)

And the outputs: http://maratona.ime.usp.br/hist/2008/primeira-fase/testset2008/principal/G.sol

- Set is a game of cards in which each card may have *one, two or three figures*.
- All figures in *one given card* are equal.
- Figures may be *circles, squares or triangles*.
- ***Each card***, therefore, has two characteristics: ***the number of figures*** and ***the type of figure***.

A set is a group of three cards such that, for each characteristic (*number* and *figure*):  Either the three cards are equal or the three cards are different.

[image]

1. (a) is a valid set, since all cards have the same figure type and
   all of them have a different number of figures.
2. (b),
   both the type of figures and the number of figures are different,
   making also a valid set. On the other hand,
3. (c) is not a valid set,
   as the last two cards have the same figure, which is different from
   the figure in the first card.
4. (d) and (e) are valid, both have the same figure type and same figure number.

With a very large deck (amount of cards given) finding the optimal approach in which the highest number of sets can be found can be troublesome.

In some cases, by removing in this specific order, all:

1. ***same figure type, different amount***.
2. ***different figure type, different amount***.
3. ***same figure type, same amount***.

Is the optimal approach but in some cases it's not, in these other cases, removing in the following order:

1. ***different figure type, different amount***.
2. ***same figure type, different amount***.
3. ***same figure type, same amount***.

Is the optimal approach and lastly, in other cases removing:

***same figure type, same amount***...and so on and so forth is the best optimal approach.

I could brute force it and perform all searches and use the one which finds the most, but it's obviously not ideal. Now, I've been trying to figure the underlying issue that makes one approach better than the other in a specific case and I just can't figure it out. I've tried checking `even`/`odd` amount of each type of card but there is no pattern between right and wrong approach.

Any ideas on how to find which approach is best? Code:

```
#include <iostream>
enum CardType
{
    SQUARE_ONE,
    SQUARE_TWO,
    SQUARE_THREE,
    CIRCLE_ONE,
    CIRCLE_TWO,
    CIRCLE_THREE,
    TRIANGLE_ONE,
    TRIANGLE_TWO,
    TRIANGLE_THREE
};
constexpr int FIGURE_MAX = 9;

class Set
{
private:
    int m_Amount {0};
public:
    int GetAmount() const { return m_Amount; }
private:
    void IncreaseAmountOfMatches() {m_Amount++;}
    int m_arrCards[FIGURE_MAX] {0};
public:
    void ReadCards(int N);
    void PerformMatching();

    void PerformMatching_SameType_DiffAmount();
    void PerformMatching_DiffType_DiffAmount();
    void PerformMatching_SameType_SameAmount();

    void Reset();
private:

    CardType GetCardByName(const std::string& name);
    inline void DecreaseType(CardType type1, CardType type2, CardType type3);
    inline void DecreaseThreeOfExactlyEqualType(CardType type);
};

void Set::Reset()
{
    m_Amount = 0;
    for(int i{0}; i<FIGURE_MAX; i++) {
        m_arrCards[i] = 0;
    }
}

void Set::ReadCards(int N)
{
    Reset();
    static std::string name;
    for(int i{0}; i<N; i++){
        std::getline(std::cin, name);
        m_arrCards[GetCardByName(name)]++;
    }
}
inline void Set::DecreaseThreeOfExactlyEqualType(CardType type)
{
    if(m_arrCards[type] >= 3) {
        m_arrCards[type] -= 3;
        IncreaseAmountOfMatches();
    }
}
inline void Set::DecreaseType(CardType type1, CardType type2, CardType type3)
{
    if(m_arrCards[type1] && m_arrCards[type2] && m_arrCards[type3])
    {
        m_arrCards[type1]--;
        m_arrCards[type2]--;
        m_arrCards[type3]--;
        IncreaseAmountOfMatches();
    }
}

void Set::PerformMatching_SameType_DiffAmount()
{
    while(true) //SAMETYPE, DIFFAMOUNT
    {
        int currentAmount = GetAmount();
        //Same Square
        DecreaseType(SQUARE_ONE, SQUARE_TWO, SQUARE_THREE);
        //Same Circle
        DecreaseType(CIRCLE_ONE, CIRCLE_TWO, CIRCLE_THREE);
        //Same Triangle
        DecreaseType(TRIANGLE_ONE, TRIANGLE_TWO, TRIANGLE_THREE);

        if(currentAmount == GetAmount()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Set::PerformMatching_DiffType_DiffAmount()
{
    while(true) //DIFFTYPE, DIFFAMOUNT
    {
        const int currentAmount = GetAmount();

        //Different Squares
        DecreaseType(SQUARE_ONE, CIRCLE_TWO, TRIANGLE_THREE);
        DecreaseType(SQUARE_ONE, TRIANGLE_THREE, CIRCLE_TWO);

        DecreaseType(SQUARE_TWO, CIRCLE_ONE, TRIANGLE_THREE);
        DecreaseType(SQUARE_TWO, CIRCLE_THREE, TRIANGLE_ONE);

        DecreaseType(SQUARE_THREE, CIRCLE_ONE, TRIANGLE_TWO);
        DecreaseType(SQUARE_THREE, CIRCLE_TWO, TRIANGLE_ONE);

        //Different Circles
        DecreaseType(CIRCLE_ONE, SQUARE_TWO, TRIANGLE_THREE);
        DecreaseType(CIRCLE_ONE, SQUARE_THREE, TRIANGLE_TWO);

        DecreaseType(CIRCLE_TWO, SQUARE_ONE, TRIANGLE_THREE);
        DecreaseType(CIRCLE_TWO, SQUARE_THREE, TRIANGLE_ONE);

        DecreaseType(CIRCLE_THREE, SQUARE_TWO, TRIANGLE_ONE);
        DecreaseType(CIRCLE_THREE, SQUARE_ONE, TRIANGLE_TWO);

        //Different Triangles
        DecreaseType(TRIANGLE_ONE, SQUARE_TWO, CIRCLE_THREE);
        DecreaseType(TRIANGLE_ONE, SQUARE_THREE, CIRCLE_TWO);

        DecreaseType(TRIANGLE_TWO, SQUARE_ONE, CIRCLE_THREE);
        DecreaseType(TRIANGLE_TWO, SQUARE_THREE, CIRCLE_ONE);

        DecreaseType(TRIANGLE_THREE, SQUARE_ONE, CIRCLE_TWO);
        DecreaseType(TRIANGLE_THREE, SQUARE_TWO, CIRCLE_ONE);

        //No more matches available
        if(currentAmount == GetAmount()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Set::PerformMatching_SameType_SameAmount()
{
    while(true)//SAMETYPE, SAMAMOUNT
    {
        int currentAmount = GetAmount();

        DecreaseThreeOfExactlyEqualType(SQUARE_ONE);
        DecreaseThreeOfExactlyEqualType(SQUARE_TWO);
        DecreaseThreeOfExactlyEqualType(SQUARE_THREE);

        DecreaseThreeOfExactlyEqualType(CIRCLE_ONE);
        DecreaseThreeOfExactlyEqualType(CIRCLE_TWO);
        DecreaseThreeOfExactlyEqualType(CIRCLE_THREE);

        DecreaseThreeOfExactlyEqualType(TRIANGLE_ONE);
        DecreaseThreeOfExactlyEqualType(TRIANGLE_TWO);
        DecreaseThreeOfExactlyEqualType(TRIANGLE_THREE);

        if(currentAmount == GetAmount()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Set::PerformMatching()
{
    //how to know the best approach?
    bool bestApproach = true; //what to do here?
    if(bestApproach) //.....
    {
        PerformMatching_SameType_DiffAmount();
        PerformMatching_DiffType_DiffAmount();
    }
    else
    {
        PerformMatching_DiffType_DiffAmount();
        PerformMatching_SameType_DiffAmount();
    }
    PerformMatching_SameType_SameAmount();
}

CardType Set::GetCardByName(const std::string& name)
{
    if(!name.compare("um quadrado")) return CardType::SQUARE_ONE;
    if(!name.compare("dois quadrados")) return CardType::SQUARE_TWO;
    if(!name.compare("tres quadrados")) return CardType::SQUARE_THREE;

    if(!name.compare("um circulo")) return CardType::CIRCLE_ONE;
    if(!name.compare("dois circulos")) return CardType::CIRCLE_TWO;
    if(!name.compare("tres circulos")) return CardType::CIRCLE_THREE;

    if(!name.compare("um triangulo")) return CardType::TRIANGLE_ONE;
    if(!name.compare("dois triangulos")) return CardType::TRIANGLE_TWO;

    return CardType::TRIANGLE_THREE;
}

int main()
{
    static int cardAmount {0};
    Set gameInstance;
    while(true)
    {
        std::cin >> cardAmount;
        std::cin.ignore();
        if(cardAmount == 0) {
            break;
        }

        gameInstance.ReadCards(cardAmount);
        gameInstance.PerformMatching();
        std::cout << gameInstance.GetAmount() << "\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the limit on the number of cards in the deck and What is expected time-complexity? Can you share link to original problem?

Comment: The right approach will be mixed... you will not find the optimum if you remove ALL sets of a specific type first. To me this whole thing sounds like a knapsack-problem, thats optimally solved by trying to remove a card (find all possible sets for this card) from the deck and then trying to solve the rest of the puzzle (recursion). Then compare the result with the result of not removing this card from the deck (recursion without ever combining the specific card with anything)

Comment: Once the problem is solved, there will be room for optimization by pre-sorting or grouping the cards in order to reduce recursion depth.

Comment: here is the original problem, also updated question https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1090

Comment: Inputs: http://maratona.ime.usp.br/hist/2008/primeira-fase/testset2008/principal/G.in

Outputs: http://maratona.ime.usp.br/hist/2008/primeira-fase/testset2008/principal/G.sol

Comment: I just noticed, in your lists you forgot to mention **different figure type, same amount**. This should also be a valid combination as far as I understand?

Comment: Could you clarify how you *know* that always one of your strategies leads to the correct answer? I mean, intuitively, I would assume that this is an NP-hard problem that cannot be solved that easily.

Comment: @sebrockm by reading the inputs/outputs I've posted. in one setup some answers are correct while others miss 1-5 sets, if compiled in other setup those missing are correct and the previous correct ones are then wrong, missing a few sets too

Comment: The available code here is to be used at the judge website, you can modify it to read the file `G.in` available here instead of user input and check the outputs

Comment: I understand. But the test data contains only 54 decks. This is a tiny number compared to the amount of decks one could imagine (in fact it's an infinite amount). So, the fact that for those 54 always one of your approaches works, could well be a coincident. There could be other decks for which non of your approaches will give the correct result.

Comment: @grek40, no that is not true. `different figure type, same amount` would not be a set

Comment: @ViníciusMagalhãesHorta Yes, it would be. If the figures are all different, but there's always the same amount, that's a set. From the problem: **"A set is a group of three cards such that, for each characteristic (number and figure), either the three cards are equal or the three cards are different."**

Comment: @sebrockm, I guess you didn't get it, my approach doesn't work for all those 54 decks. If I try *approach one*, it'll solve ~48 decks and those 6 remaining it won't find all sets because *approach one* isn't optimal for them.
If I try *approach two*, it'll solve those 6 that *approach one* didn't, but it won't solve all 54 decks because *approach two* won't be optimal to some decks whilst *approach one* was.

This is true for all aproaches mentioned

Comment: @sweenish. *three cards are equal* = same type, same amount. *three cards are different* = different type, different amount. It doesn't state there that *same type, different amount* is a set though (which it is!)

Comment: `different figure type, same amount` = 1 triangle, 1 square, 1 circle. that is not a set

Comment: @ViníciusMagalhãesHorta Yes, it is a set. For each figure, they are all different. For each number, they are all the same. That qualifies it as a set, per the definition from the problem that I pasted above. This lack of understanding the rules of the problem could easily be leading to the lack of a unified solution. I am not new to the game of Set.

Comment: Wikipedia says this game is NP-complete: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game)#Complexity So, neither one of your two approaches, nor a combined approach (try app 1, then app 2, take the maximum) can be a valid solution. Otherwise you'd just have proven that P=NP and you'd win some million dollars ;) But I'm not sure if I understood what you *actually* want to do? Maybe you are fine with having only an approximation of a solution... in that case could you please clarify what you want to do, as it's not clear to me at all.

Comment: I'm glad I asked about the `different figure type, same amount`... didn't expect this to turn into a debate, but it's really crucial if you want to find a solution that passes the official test suite :)

Comment: Well, I just want to solve this particular problem.. :-P

Comment: Helping me figure why one of my approaches work in some cases and in some not is what I really need. I wouldn't be interested in solving the *correct* set game, just this problem in particular. If I were capable of knowing why one approach works best in one case and in others doesn't, that'd satisfy.

Comment: @sebrockm your linked wikipedia complexity doesn't fully apply here... the question is about combining the optimal amount of sets from a game where all cards are open simultaneously, but wiki talks about the actual game and the task of finding **ANY** set from the currently open cards.

Comment: @grek40 I'm not sure if I understand your concern. Is it only about finding *the best numer of sets* vs. finding *any* set? In that case the complexity of wikipedia still applies here be simple polynomial reduction: if you have a polynomial algorithm to find the best number of sets you can trivially use this algorithm to tell if there is any result at all. So this polynomial algorithm would solve an NP-complete problem, which makes the problem it was actually designed for NP-complete as well.

Comment: @sebrockm a Problem being NP-Complete regarding the number of properties and values is restricted for a specific number of properties (3) and values (3). And finding N sets instead of a single set *could* be more or less efficient than N times finding one.

Comment: @grek40 The following is true for every problem, not only this one: If you have an algorithm that counts the number of solutions for your problem, you can use that very same algorithm to determine if there is any solution at all. That means, if the problem "is there any solution?" is (NP-)hard, the corresponding problem "how many solutions are there?" cannot be simpler. The approaches the OP presents here are polynomial. If they were correct, they would solve the NP-complete problem "is there any" in polynomial time which would make the OP rich and famous.

Comment: @sebrockm Lets look at another passage from the same wiki article: *"The largest group of cards that can be put together without creating a set is 20"* So no matter how large my card deck is, if I thouroughly inspect up to 21 cards from the set, I'm guaranteed to find a set. Doesn't sound very NP-ish to me.

Comment: @grek40 ok I see your point now. Sorry, my bad, I didn't get earlier what you mean :) But then it remains unknown, if this can be solved easily

Comment: @sweenish, I finally solved the problem. You were right `different figure type, same amount` is indeed a set of cards.... w-o-w! I'll never again so quickly disconsider what others tell me. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this problem is to understand that no greedy strategy can work, because a counter-example can always be constructed that defeats it.

You need to handle all combinations to win against this problem with one important caveat: You can simplify the problem by removing each triple set of the same card and then solve the problem for the remaining cards. I was surprised that we only need to keep 1-3 cards of each type to get the correct results.

So a solution in pseudo-code:

```
allowed_sets = ... // Determine the set of all valid sets of 3 cards

simple_problem, number_of_sets_simplified = simplify(problem) // Reduce problem by removing triples of cards

result = number_of_sets_simplified + solve(simple_problem)

int solve(Problem problem)
{     
   int best_score = 0;
   for (set : allowed_sets)
   {
     if (problem.can_remove(set))
     {
       int score = solve(problem.remove(set)) + 1;
       if (best_score < score)
         best_score = score;
     }
   }
   return best_score;
}
```

Solution in Ruby (with a cache for already computed solutions and as a depth-first search implemented using a queue because I was worried about stack overflow):

```
# Build array of allowed sets
cards = ["um", "dois", "tres"].product(["quadrado", "circulo", "triangulo"])
allowed_sets = cards.repeated_combination(3).to_a
allowed_sets.select! { |s|
  [0,1].all? { |i|
  (s[0][i] == s[1][i] && s[0][i] == s[2][i]) ||
  (s[0][i] != s[1][i] && s[0][i] != s[2][i] && s[1][i] != s[2][i])
  }
}

puts allowed_sets.inspect

# Convert to index array for the number of cards in the set for each of the 9 possible cards
allowed_sets.map! { |s|
  nset = [0] * 9

  s.each { |l|
    nset[cards.find_index(l)] += 1
  }

  nset
}

puts allowed_sets.inspect


# Read problems from G.in
problems = []
nset = nil
File.readlines("G.in", chomp: true).each { |l|

  if l =~ /\d+/
    problems << nset if nset
    nset = [0] * 9
  else 
    i = cards.find_index(l.chomp("s").split)
    nset[i] += 1
  end  
}

cache = {}
queue = []

problems.each { |problem|

  # Simplify task by removing as many triple sets of the same card without being greedy
  result = 0
  problem.map! { |i| 

    if i < 1
      i
    else
      a = (i-1) / 3
      result += a
      i - 3 * a
    end
  }

  puts "Problem to solve: " + problem.inspect

  queue = [problem]  
  while queue.size > 0
    current_set = queue.pop

    any_missing = false
    max = nil

    any_allowed = false

    # Check each set
    allowed_sets.each { |set_to_check|

      # Do we have enough remaining cards for this set
      if (0..8).to_a.all? { |i| set_to_check[i] <= current_set[i] } 

        next_set = current_set.dup
        (0..8).to_a.each { |j| next_set[j] -= set_to_check[j] }

        if next_set.sum < 3
          cache[next_set] = 0
        end

        if cache.has_key?(next_set)
          max = cache[next_set] + 1 if !max || max < cache[next_set] + 1
        else
          queue << current_set if !any_missing
          queue << next_set
          any_missing = true
        end

        any_allowed = true
      end

    }

    if any_allowed
      if !any_missing
        cache[current_set] = max
      end 
    else
      cache[current_set] = 0      
    end

  end

  puts "Number of sets: #{cache[problem] + result}"
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your point *"You can simplify the problem by removing each triple set of the same card and then solve the problem for the remaining cards. I was surprised that we only need to keep 1-3 cards of each type [...]"* Do you mean its sufficient to keep 3 cards of the same type for the final resolution or do you mean that all cards of the same type could be removed if thats possible?

Comment: If you have 9 cards of the same type, you can solve the problem with 3 and add `(9-6) / 3 = 2` to your final result.

Comment: Ive no idea how to implement a C++ version as I'm unable to understand Ruby code logic

Comment: I'll just go ahead and award the bounty to you, as it seems that the question won't achieve further attention. But if you can, please comment your whole code on what every line of it does. That'd be incredibly helpful. Thank you again for taking the your time.

Comment: @ViníciusMagalhãesHorta Later today I am going to post a long answer; I think Christopher's result, while inspiring, is not entirely correct and especially, a more elegant solution is possible.

Comment: @Hagadol thankyou Very much for doing that, especially now that the bounty has already been awarded

Comment: @ViníciusMagalhãesHorta I'm sorry, I won't manage today; I found a problem with my solution. I hope I can still fix it and come back to you as soon as possible (mainly because I enjoy the problem).

Comment: Okay, I'll be waiting

Answer (score 1):

General note to other readers: the author of the question explicitely commented that only the three set types **same figure type, same amount**, **same figure type, different amount** and **different figure type, different amount** are valid.

This problem should not be confused with the linked set problem, where the case **different figure type, same amount** would also be valid.

---

The following example demonstrates, that all of your proposed starting actions lead to a situation, where the optimum can no longer be reached.

For the sake of short uniform identifiers I use `c` for `circulo(s)`, `q` for `quadrado(s)` and `t` for `triangulo(s)`, followed by the number `1`, `2` or `3` instead of the words `um`, `dois`, `tres`.

Example input:

```
c1
c1
c1
c2
c2
c3
q1
q1
q2
q2
q3
q3
t1
t1
t1
t2
t3
t3
```

#### Start 1: same figure type, same amount.

```
c1 c1 c1
t1 t1 t1
```

Since you commented that this could be solved by next applying **same type, different amount**:

```
q1 q2 q3
q1 q2 q3
```

different type, different amount

```
No match.
Remaining:
c2
c2
c3
t2
t3
t3
```

#### Start 2: same figure type, different amount.

```
c1 c2 c3
q1 q2 q3
q1 q2 q3
t1 t2 t3
```

#### Start 3: different figure type, different amount.

```
c1 q2 t3
c1 q2 t3
c1 t2 q3
t1 c2 q3
```

#### Observation

With each start, trying to resolve the remaining items with the two other strategies will not resolve all items into sets (even if you try to be smart instead of applying them one after another).

#### Actual solution would solve into a perfect amount of sets

```
c1 c1 c1
q1 q2 q3
t1 t2 t3
q1 c2 t3
t1 c2 q3
t1 q2 c3
```

As you can see, in each of the 3 starts, where one single selection strategy is used until it no longer applies, a set is selected, that is not part of the perfect solution. Instead, this additional set leads to a situation, where crucial items are missing to complete the sets with different strategies.

So we can conclude that the best approach can't generally consist of just applying the three different strategies in any order, even though there are input examples, where applying the strategies in order works.

Comment: uh, it seems that your solution applies:1: `same type, same amount` -> 2:`same type, different amount` -> 3:`different type, different amount`...

Comment: Which in the use of my program, is optimal for some decks (like yours) and some not. some decks; 1:`different type, different amount` -> 2:`same type, different amount` -> 3: `same type, same amount` would be optimal. some others 1: `same type, different amount` -> 2: `same type, same amount` -> 3:`different type, different amount` is optimal...and so on and so forth. I guess you get the picture

Comment: The exclusion of a valid matching strategy is either highlighting OP's misunderstanding of what a set is, or that the question they are attempting to solve is fundamentally flawed. Note that on that page, same shape but different numbers is a valid set. Not counting the inverse is a massive error on someone's part.

Comment: @ViníciusMagalhãesHorta I edited your suggested continuation to **Start 1**. How is this a solution? Or did I miss something there?

Comment: @ViníciusMagalhãesHorta apart from all logic concerns, I just realized that your code for `PerformMatching_DiffType_DiffAmount` looks wrong. `DecreaseType(SQUARE_ONE, CIRCLE_TWO, TRIANGLE_THREE);` and `DecreaseType(SQUARE_ONE, TRIANGLE_THREE, CIRCLE_TWO);` are basically removing the same set of cards. Maybe you have more errors like this.